# Excel vba, compare rows of two workbooks and replace

Tags: vba, excel, compare, rows

Here is a bit of background on what I'm trying to achieve.

I have an excel file, which contains 10 sheets and each of the sheets contain many rows of data. This workbook is sent to different people and each one fills in their respective info,only in columns A,B. I have made a vba script which loops through all the filled in workbooks, and checks which rows have cells `Ax`, `Bx` filled. Then it copies those in a new workbook.

So what I have right now is:

1. A workbook which contains only the rows of which the columns A,B have been filled.
2. A workbook which contains all unfilled rows. (the initial one)

What I want to do now is check row by row, and find e.g. Row 1 of sheet1 of workbook **A**, minus columns A,B, in workbook's **B** sheet 1. After the row is found I need to replace workbook's **B** row with the one from workbook **A**.

So in the end I will be left with one master workbook (previously workbook **B**) that will contain both filled and unfilled rows.

I hope I didn't make this too complicated. Any insight on what is the best way to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: `Any insight on what is the best way to achieve this would be appreciated.` What according to you is the best way? You must have given some thought to it :) Have you tried any code yet? Show us the code that you tried and on the basis of that we can tell you if that is the best way or if it can be improved ;)

Comment: Well, the way which I had in mind is the simplest I could think of. Looping through the lines of the first workbook, find each one of them in the second workbook and replace them. With that said, I don't know how to compare ranges. workbook1.sheet1.range("C1:F1") = orkbook2.sheet1.range("C1:F1") ? And then replace the whole line. I haven't created any code yet, because I'm not sure this is the best way. There are many lines of data and it might be an overkill this way.

Comment: Yes Looping will be an overkill. You might want to use `.FIND` See if this gets you started. http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: This looks like it will work nicely. Thanks. I will get back with progress, as soon as I've made some :)

Comment: Well I'm able to give .find a range object to look for, but the results are not correct. Is there a guide on how to use .find to look for a range? From what I understand though I first need to convert the range to an array and check cell by cell. If that is really the case it kinda defeats the purpose, doesn't it?

Comment: No it doesn't as it doesn't loop the cell like a for loop does. If you can upload an sample workbook, then maybe I can show you an example?

Comment: Hm ok. Here is a sample of workbooks a and b, I'm describing above: http://www.mediafire.com/?a17og2o43fz7086

Comment: So you want to copy from WB-A to WB-B if a match is found? And a match would be if Col C to Col L match I presume?

Comment: Yes exactly. This would do for this example, but different sheets have different column range. I think it will be ok if you give me an example for C-L. I will be able to figure it out for the rest.

Comment: Ok which column in C to L is unique? In the sense the values are not duplicated in that column?

Comment: From the data I've collected so far, there is no indication that a value in a column is unique. That's why I need to match all the cells to make sure that replacement is correct :( note:I'm able to do this task manually by using advanced filters. I don't know if this would be easier to implement in a vba script than .find.

Comment: Posting a code shortly which uses .Find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comments, it is possible to use `.Find` for what you are trying to achieve. The below code sample opens workbooks `A` and `B`. It then loops through the values of Col C in Workbook `A` and tries to find the occurrence of that value in Col C of Workbook `B`. If a match is found then it compares all columns in that row. And if all columns match then it writes to Col A and Col B of workbook `B` based on what the value is in workbook `A`. Once the match is found it uses `.FindNext` for further matches in Col C.

To test this, Save the files that you gave me as `C:\A.xls` and `C:\B.xls` respectively. Now open a new workbook and in a module paste this code. The code is comparing `Sheet7` of workbook `A` with `Sheet7` of workbook `B`

*I am sure you can now amend it for rest of the sheets*

**TRIED AND TESTED** (See Snapshot at end of post)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws1LRow As Long, ws2LRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ws1LCol As Long, ws2LCol As Long
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean, matchFound As Boolean

    '~~> Open File 1
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\A.xls")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("sheet7")
    '~~> Get the last Row and Last Column
    With ws1
        ws1LRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws1LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    '~~> Open File 2
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\B.xls")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("sheet7")
    '~~> Get the last Row and Last Column
    With ws2
        ws2LRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws2LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    '~~> Loop Through Cells of Col C in workbook A and try and find it
    '~~> in Col C of workbook 2
    For i = 2 To ws1LRow
        SearchString = ws1.Range("C" & i).Value

        Set aCell = ws2.Columns(3).Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        ExitLoop = False

        '~~> If match found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            matchFound = True

            '~~> Then compare all columns
            For j = 4 To ws1LCol
                If ws1.Cells(i, j).Value <> ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value Then
                    matchFound = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            '~~> If all columns matched then wrtie to Col A/B
            If matchFound = True Then
                ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value
                ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If

            '~~> Find Next Match
            Do While ExitLoop = False
                Set aCell = ws2.Columns(3).FindNext(After:=aCell)

                '~~> If match found
                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                    matchFound = True

                    '~~> Then compare all columns
                    For j = 4 To ws1LCol
                        If ws1.Cells(i, j).Value <> ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value Then
                            matchFound = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next

                    '~~> If all columns matched then wrtie to Col A/B
                    If matchFound = True Then
                        ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value
                        ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value
                    End If
                Else
                    ExitLoop = True
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

***BEFORE***

[image]

***AFTER***

[image]

Comment: Impressive! It surely works, thank you Siddharth. I'm gonna study your code, very useful stuff and easy to understand for a novice like me.

Comment: Hm, I tried using it on the real sheet7 of my workbooks but it threw runtime error 424 - object required, on line If ws1.Cells(i, j).Value <> ws12.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value Then. I will look into it.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. change `ws12` to `ws2`

Comment: lol I should have noticed it, sorry. It works perfectly :D Now I'm only a foreach sheet loop away from the goal :) Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you should consider upvoting the solution ?